# Is there any way to explore Gerudo Town without wearing the female disguise?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

It kind of irritates me that despite:

- Saving the town from Divine Beast Naboris
- Being on respected terms with both the village chief and her aide
- Wielding the Master Sword clearly proving Link is the "prophesied one"

I can still get kicked out of town even changing headgear in front of the village chief. And yet, changing into a disguise RIGHT in front of the gate guards fools them completely.

Basically, is there any way to be able to enter Gerudo Town without having to put on a disguise?

Comment: Not much fighting inside the town anyway.

Comment: @Cœur still sorta annoying to have to change clothes whenever I need to go in gerudo

Comment: Easy: play Tears of the Kingdom!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As the other answer stated, there's no way to do this on the unmodded game.

Keep in mind that [you can wear more than just the Gerudo outfit](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Gerudo_Town#Gerudo_Vai_Clothing): You can also enter Gerudo town with Thunder Helm, Sand Boots and Snow Boots, provided that you're wearing the rest of the Gerudo outfit.

---

There's multiple mods that allow this though, if you're fine with that.

[Here's one for Wii U](https://gamebanana.com/gamefiles/7004)

[Here's linkle mod for Switch, which includes a separate folder for Gate Bypass](https://gamebanana.com/skins/164945)

Answer (score 21):

In short, no

There have been countless attempts to do this, all of which failed

There seems to be a zone surrounding the town that prevents anyone from entering if they're not wearing the clothing, and that regardless of velocity at which you enter or height above the town, it's impossible to not trigger the guards

Comment: Might be good to reference these attempts.